# What harm can a cold reboot cause into your computer?

Tags: filesystem, reboot, crash, fsck

I was taking a look at the game DEFCON, and it froze my PC. Unfortunately, I only discovered the REISUB thing after a cold reboot.

Now, what harm the cold reboot caused into my computer? Any type of hardware harm, or software or security harm?

In my case, I only had Steam, the game and the system log open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a computer is shut off or loses power unexpectedly, it has no chance to finish writing data on its drives, that was only about to be written there. This can leave files and file systems in an inconsistent state.

### File System Integrity

Modern file systems like ext4 (the default in Ubuntu), NTFS (default in Windows), and HPFS+ (default in OS X) can (almost) fully mitigate the risk of file system corruption, by writing a journal onto the disk, that lets them revert or complete the partial changes leading to inconsistencies. There's one popular file system still in wide use without this capability: FAT32 (or even FAT16 and FAT12).

At each boot Ubuntu verifies automatically, that there are no half-finished actions written to journals of file system mounted during boot (with an entry in `/etc/fstab`), and fixes all such journal entries. File systems mounted manually at a later time cannot be mounted normally, if they contain such journal entries, until they are fixed.

### File Integrity

What a file system journal doesn't (normally) protect against, is applications writing incomplete data, because they were interrupted at shut-off. While the file system can be restored to consistency, such an application may have partially overwritten a file or multiple files, so they now contain half of the previous and half of the new state, which typically leaves them unusable or flawed. This is especially problematic, if such a file has an important role in the operating system or an essential program. In such a case one must often resort to a minimal recovery environment or a live DVD/USB medium to re-install the packages with the affected file.

To detect file corruption in less critical, less noticeable packages, you can have the system verify their integrity on a regular basis with [debsums](//apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/debsums/).

Comment: Here, since there was only Steam and the game running, the chances of any problems are small, right? (Tried to reinstall Steam via Software Center, but I really don't know if the reinstallation was that good, at least it works)

Comment: Yes, commonly the biggest danger is a crash or power loss during package management. Half-installed packages can be a bitch to clean up – especially if the affected packages are essential to the package manager itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to holding down the power button or unplugging the cord I know on windows computers it can corrupt your files espiclly .dll files i wouldn't make a habit of it I've done It on Ubuntu a few times and haven't seen any issues here's what you can do if a game becomes unresponsive

Ctrl alt and f1
Sign in 
Htop
Find the game and kill it (f9)
Ctrl alt f7 to get back to GUI

If you don't have htop use

```
     Sudo apt-get install htop
```

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Good to know that. but I had to hold the power button because I coudn't do anything (mouse, keyboard, sound and keyboard were all froze). Just noticed that my syslog and auth log are a little bugged (maybe because the cold reboot), is this a bad sign?

Comment: Shared libraries (Windows or *nix) cannot be damaged by a power loss or forced shut-down simply because they were in use (meaning open for reading and execution) at the time – not with modern file system. See my answer for a short explanation.

Comment: @Nori-chan: If you have an ancillary question, that is not specific to this answer, please edit your question and add it there. It's easy to miss it down here.

Comment: Powering off your computer would corrupt it if it was in the middle of saving at least on windows